# Mongo Db modeling

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose

I have two basic tables clients and packages.Clients can have multiple packages.Which approach is better

1.==================================
clients table                                    packages table
id:                                              package_id:
client name:                                     package_name:
packages: [{package_id:,package_key:}]           status:

2===================================
client table, package table and client_package pivot table

Answer (score 0):

Even if there's no MongoDB, you don't need pivot table as it is one to many relation (not many to many). With MongoDB, the approach is the same.
See [more](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/relational-databases-defining-relationships-between-database-tables/) about relationships.

Answer (score 0):

> Client can have multiple packages

Both embedding and referencing can be used with this One-to-Many relationship of client (1) and packages (N). The embedding or referencing can be done on either sides - that is four different ways of modeling. Each of the four ways has its own use case.

But, most common and simple way to do this is **embedding** the "many" side in the "one" side. This works fine when:

- the number of "many" side is a small number and size of documents are small.
- the querying of both sides data is done together.

*client:*

```
id: 1
name: "a-1"
status: true
packages: [ { id: 1, name: "abc" }, { id: 2, name: "xyz" }, ... ]
```

Note the packages are represented as an array of sub-documents. And, all the package data is embedded within the client itself - all in just one collection.

Here is the way to model with **referencing**:

This is more commonly used way of referencing - the "one" side within the "many" side. Note that many packages can have the same client in this model. This modeling is preferred when:

- there are large number of documents and with large sizes.
- the querying is often made on individual collections (rather than together).

*client:*

```
id: 1
name: "c-1"
status: true
```

*packages:*

```
id: 19
name: "pkg-01"
client: "c-1"    -- <client-name> reference
```